# Read CSV and input into Active Directory through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I export a database into CSV. In the CSV there contains fields such as employeeid, first name, last name, email, position, description, and various fields. I am trying to populate those fields and all the other fields into Active Directory. The extracted CSV fields don't directly correlate to Active Directory. because of this, I need to check for double entries; if any.

To do this, I take the email address of a user in the CSV and do a search in Active Directory for the email address. I then try to take the same users employeeid and check to see if in Active Directory employeeid attribute is filled. If the employeeid attribute is filled, skip, if not, fill in the attribute from the CSV file.

I am having trouble inputting data from the CSV to Active Directory and also doing the check if employeeID exists in the attribute.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# ERROR REPORTING ALL
Set-StrictMode -Version latest

$newpath  = "C:\Scripts\Test Files\book1.csv"
$log      = "C:\Scripts\Test Files\import_employeeID.log"
$date     = Get-Date
$addn     = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName
$dnsroot  = (Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot
$i        = 1

function Start-Commands {
  Update-Users
}

function Update-Users {
  "Processing started (on " + $date + "): " | Out-File $log -Append
  "---------------------------------------" | Out-File $log -Append
  Import-CSV $newpath | ForEach-Object {
    $UserEmail  = $_.EMAILID
    $EmployeeID = $_.EMPLID
    $LastName   = $_.LAST_NAME
    $FIRSTNAME  = $_.FIRST_NAME

    $UserEmail
  } -Properties EmployeeID
  $CheckUser = $user.employeeid
  if ($CheckUser) {
    Write-Host "$UserEmail $EmployeeID UPDATED"     
    "$UserEmail $EmployeeID UPDATED `r" | Out-File $log -Append
  } else {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $User | Set-ADUser -EmployeeID $EmployeeID
    Get-ADUser -Identity $User | Set-ADUser -Replace @{info=$EmployeeID}
  }
  $i++
}
"--------------------------------------------" + "`r`n" | Out-File $log -Append
}

Write-Host "STARTED SCRIPT`r`n"
Start-Commands
Write-Host "STOPPED SCRIPT"
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is not working or what you expect that is not happening? _having trouble_ is not a good start of a question.

Comment: There are several syntax errors in the code you posted.

Comment: It didn't seem like my script pasted all the way, but here it is

$User = Get-ADUser -filter {EmailAddress -eq $UserEmail} -Properties EmployeeID
    $CheckUser = $user.employeeid
    if ($CheckUser)
    {
 Write-Host "$UserEmail $EmployeeID UPDATED"  
 "$UserEmail $EmployeeID UPDATED `r" | Out-File $log -append
 }

The $User = Get-ADUser -filter {EmailAddress -eq $UserEmail} -Properties EmployeeID

doesn't seem to be returning anything and if it does, I need it to check against Active Directory EmployeeID attribute.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: thanks. i figured out my code.